# The below PLSQL Condition seems Ok but getting PLS-00103 Exception

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
if (insflag = 'P' and (dd_flag = 'DC' || dd_flag != 'CC' || dd_flag != 'BC' || dd_flag != 'AC')) then
{
        select * from tabOne;
}
elsif (del_flag = 'DC' || del_flag = 'CC' || del_flag = 'BC' || del_flag = 'AC') then
{
        select * from tabTwo;
}
```

**Exception:**

```
 PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "=" when expecting one of the
         following:
         . ( ) , * @ % & - + / at mod remainder rem <an exponent (**)>
         and or as ||
         The symbol ")" was substituted for "=" to continue.
```

Comment: PLS- means a compilation error, not an exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It *seems OK*? I don't think so. This is Oracle's PL/SQL, so:

- `OR` should be used, not double pipe `||` (that's *concatenation* operator in Oracle)
- no curly brackets
- you're missing `END IF`

When fixed:

```
   IF (    insflag = 'P'
       AND (   dd_flag = 'DC'
            OR dd_flag != 'CC'
            OR dd_flag != 'BC'
            OR dd_flag != 'AC'))
   THEN
      SELECT * FROM tabOne;
   ELSIF (   del_flag = 'DC'
          OR del_flag = 'CC'
          OR del_flag = 'BC'
          OR del_flag = 'AC')
   THEN
      SELECT * FROM tabTwo;
   END IF;
```

However, that's still wrong and won't work because - in PL/SQL - you have to select **into** *something*. `select *` suggests that you'll be selecting all rows from these tables so you most probably can't use a scalar variable. One option is to use bulk operation and select *everything* into an array.

Basically, it depends on what you want to do.

Comment: Also, PL/SQL syntax doesn't need brackets around `if` conditions, because they are already terminated by `then`. (It also doesn't require uppercase, but let's not go there.)